# Implement Multisite in wordpress in sub directories

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to implement multisite so that I can add several other blogs.

I added `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` line of code in wp-config.php file under `define('WPLANG', '');`

When I look at the configure network panel I get this message:

"Because your install is not new, the sites in your WordPress network must use sub-domains. The main site in a sub-directory install will need to use a modified permalink structure, potentially breaking existing links."

I want all my blogs to be in sub directories.

```
Like : http://abcd.com/site1, http://abcd.com/site2, http://abcd.com/site3
```

What should I do so that I can proceed with installing the multisite option using sub directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Try adding the following code in your themes functions.php . It w

```
add_filter( 'allow_subdirectory_install',
create_function( '', 'return true;' )
);
```

That’s it. Now reload the Network page and you will see option to choose between sub-domain and sub-directory. Once done remove the code from functions.php.

Source [tip credit](https://prowebexpert.com/2017/06/06/solution-for-because-your-install-is-not-new-the-sites-in-your-wordpress-network-must-use-sub-domains/)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#Switching_network_types

But please note that if your site is older than a month, you might have serious conflict issues between pages and sites.  Read the directions I provided, and read the cautions.  As always, BACK UP YOUR DATABASE AND FILES... including the wp-config.php and .htaccess files :)

Answer (score 0):

This process still works as of WordPress 6.4.3 but if you are using PHP 8, you need to use the following code as [create_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) has been removed (and deprecated as of PHP 7.2). As recommended, create_function() has been replaced with an anonymous function.

```
add_filter( 'allow_subdirectory_install', function() { return true; } );
```